# Rstudio cloud. Download a project

Tags: r, download, cloud, rstudio, project

Since Rstudio cloud is no longer free, I'd like to download my projects from it. I found a lot of information how to download files from the projects, but I need to download the projects themselves, because I'd like to keep on working on them and be able to use my previous code. Is there any option to reach this, except copying code from every single project as a text?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Using the terminal in RStudio Cloud, you can create a zipped file of entire working directory: `tar -czf my_project_name.zip .`, and then download the compressed file (in the Files tab: "More >> Export"). Repeat this for each workspace.